# Knockout style binding with three options

Tags: binding, knockout.js, styles

Alright, so I have used the KO style binding extensively to show inline-validation of user inputted data, and it works great.  Here's one of my bindings:

```
data-bind='style: {backgroundPosition: ! currentRegistry().title() || !$root.currentRegistry().clientLogin()  ? "top" : "bottom"}
```

The trouble I'm having is that I want to do a binding like this, except that on the second style binding, if the if statement evaluates to false I'd like it to return to whatever background position was set by the previous binding, rather than just going back to "bottom":

```
data-bind='style: {backgroundPosition: ! currentRegistry().title() || !$root.currentRegistry().clientLogin()  ? "top" : "bottom"}, style: {backgroundPosition: currentRegistry().title() && $root.currentRegistry().clientLogin() && ! $root.hasRegImage()  ? "20px" : "bottom"}'
```

In other words, for the second binding I'd like to say style: {backgroundPosition: if stuff ? "THIS"} else don't change the style.  Hope that makes sense, any hints or pointers to make this happen would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Edit:

Although RodneyTrotter's solution is undoubtedly the more elegant way to get this same functionality, I did learn a method from a colleague that does EXACTLY what I was asking.  I didn't realize that you could make each property conditional, aka:

```
data-bind='style: {backgroundPosition: ! $root.currentRegistry().clientLogin() || ! $root.currentRegistry().title()  ? "top" :  (! $root.hasRegImage()  ? "20px" : "bottom")}'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the css binding to achieve this (note: you may need to play around with the ordering of the css classes to achieve the desired result)

HTML

```
<div id='myElement'
    data-bind='css: {
        'foo': !currentRegistry().title() || !$root.currentRegistry().clientLogin(), 
        'bar': currentRegistry().title() && $root.currentRegistry().clientLogin() && ! $root.hasRegImage()
    }'>
    Hello, i am the div content.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myElement{
    background-position: bottom;
}

#myElement.foo {
    background-position:top;
}

#myElement.bar {
    background-position:20px;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the most elegant and proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure this is answering your question exactly, but this is also valid and quite helpful:

`'style': someCondition ? {'max-height': '100px'} : {}`

Allowing you to leave the styling alone if the condition is not met.

---

Furthermore, if you're using components, you can call

`'style': $component.getStyling($data)`

And then within `getStyling` perform some multiline if-statment logic to construct the objects holding the styling.

Same applies to `css` binding.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an addition even though you've already accepted an answer.  I think "separation of concerns" is an important concept to keep in mind as you continue to work with Knockout.

It's generally considered a best practice to keep your logic in your view model, your styles in your CSS, and both of them out of your bindings / html.  There are several benefits, but primarily it makes for cleaner more maintainable code.  Rodney's answer moved you one good step in the right direction.

In terms of your original post, you'd want to add functions to your view model in order to get your logic out of the bindings.  For example,

```
var viewModel = {
    backgroundStyle : function($root){
        return !$root.currentRegistry().clientLogin() || 
            !$root.currentRegistry().title()  ? 
            "top" :  
                (! $root.hasRegImage()  ? "20px" : "bottom");
    }
}
```

and then your binding would simply be written as :

```
<div data-bind="style : {backgroundPosition : backgroundStyle($root)}"></div>
```

### One More Step

Of course, we've moved the logic out of the binding, but now we've got the style in the logic.  One more separation ala Rodney's answer and we have...

```
#myElement{
    background-position: bottom;
}

#myElement.foo {
    background-position:top;
}

#myElement.bar {
    background-position:20px;
}
```

with a view model of

```
var viewModel = {
    decideClassName : function($root){
        return !$root.currentRegistry().clientLogin() || 
            !$root.currentRegistry().title()  ? 
            "foo" :  (! $root.hasRegImage()  ? "bar" : "");
    }
}
```

and our binding becomes

```
<div data-bind="css : decideClassName($root)}"></div>
```

---

I should also point out that this type of dynamic CSS class name binding is only available in Knockout version 2.2.0 or later [as per Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/).

---

Keeping your code organized and "concerns separated" in this way can help you easily find bugs, make changes, work with teams, and probably most importantly can lead you to make good implementation decisions.  I recently [helped someone on the Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/zTC96WDW2Mw) who would have easily found their answer if they had their logic in their view model and not their bindings.

I hope this info is helpful!